# Can't move partition in GParted

Tags: 14.04, gparted

I'm running dual boot 14.0 and windows, I freed up some space from the windows partition using GParted. Now I can't seem to allocate it to the Ubuntu partition. Neither partition show the possibility of being moved and I understand the unallocated one must be to the right of the extended Ubuntu partition.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! ;-) Did you "apply changes" before trying to move?  If yes, could you post a screen shot (in the comments)?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the ubuntu partition right now? You cant modify a mounted partition. You have to boot up with a live environment, e.g. Ubuntu from a USB stick to modify the partition.

Answer (score 0):

Simply freeing up space in windows partition will not give you extra space in ubuntu partition.The space you have freed is currently not utilized by either ubuntu or windows.

What you have to do now, is increase the size of Ubuntu partition to add that un-utilized space into the Ubuntu partition.

But, as @owang pointed out, you cannot modify a mounted partition.i.e You cannot expand(or shrink) your partition while using it.You have two options:

1.Boot using an Ubuntu USB stick into live environment to modify the partition(i.e use gparted from live environment), or

2.Boot into windows and use gparted like software alternatives available for Windows(try [EaseUS Partition Master](http://www.easeus.com/partition-manager/) or [Parted magic](http://partedmagic.com))